# Spark (python) dataframe collect random OOM error

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, collect

I have a small Spark (v 2.1.1) cluster of 2 worker nodes and 1 driver node. Hardware configuration as follows:
Master/Driver node - 4 core, 8gb RAM
Workers - 4 core, 16gb RAM

Spark properties for the spark-submit job are here - [Spark properties screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1D0c5.png). The job is straight-forward - for a given search parameter, pull the documents from an Elasticsearch cluster, and compute some metrics on the data. A spark dataframe is created from the Es documents. The dataframe has 15 columns, and the no. of rows can range anywhere from 0.5 million to 10M+ rows. The dataframe is cached as it is the source for all the metrics computations. The computations involve total counts, sums, averages, etc. Here's a code snippet of one of the computations -

```
''' Start & End journey pages '''
df_frag = df.select('visit_id', 'hit_seq_nbr', 'concategory')
df_frag = df_frag.withColumn('hit_seq_nbr', 
df_frag['hit_seq_nbr'].cast(ShortType()))
grpd = df_frag.groupby('visit_id').agg(min('hit_seq_nbr').alias('hit_min'), max('hit_seq_nbr').alias('hit_max'))
df_frag2 = df_frag.join(grpd, on='visit_id', how='left')
first_pages_df = df_frag2.select('concategory').filter('hit_seq_nbr == hit_min')\
                                           .groupby('concategory')\
                                           .agg(count('concategory').alias('page_count'))

# total = first_pages_df.select('page_count').groupBy().sum('page_count').withColumnRenamed('sum(page_count)', 'total_page_count')
# first_pages_df = first_pages_df.crossJoin(total)
# first_pages_df = first_pages_df.select('concategory',
#                                        round(100. * col('page_count') / col('total_page_count'), scale=2).alias('perc'))\
#                                .orderBy('perc', ascending=False)

total = first_pages_df.select('page_count').groupBy().sum('page_count').withColumnRenamed('sum(page_count)', 'total_page_count')
total = total.collect()[0]['total_page_count']
perc = udf(lambda r: 100. * r / total)
first_pages_df = first_pages_df.withColumn('perc', round(perc('page_count'), scale=2)).orderBy('perc', ascending=False)
# first_pages_df.show()
# print total
# print '======================='
top3_rows = first_pages_df.take(3)
the_metrics['journey_start'] = [(r.concategory, r.perc) for r in top3_rows]
dispose_dataframe([first_pages_df, grpd, total, df_frag])
```

For a dataset of 10M+ rows the cached dataframe consumes around 300MB of available Storage memory ([Spark Executors screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYXTb.png)).

The issue this spark job runs into is random OOM errors at the last computation which has a .collect() similar to the snippet above. I say random because there have been a few runs that have completed successfully, but the majority of runs have errored out with OOMs. The job runs fine with datasets of <10M rows. Also, once an OOM has been encountered the error repeats for subsequent 10M+ jobs. At this point I simply re-run the stop/start master & slave scripts. I'm looking for answers to these questions -

1. What is the reason for the OOM occurring randomnly?
2. The .collect() is applied on the last transformation, which is an aggregated dataframe. From what I have understood this should limit the size of the dataframe on which collect() is called - in most of the cases it is a single row-column dataframe - and yet the OOM occurs at this point. Is it happening that irrespective of the transformations, the entire dataset gets loaded into driver memory whenever a collect() is encountered?
3. I'm not completely convinced that it is a hardware short-coming, because of the occassional succesful run. Or is it a driver hardware shortcoming for the large datasets?

Comment: Datasets are lazy and a transformation (groupby, agg, sum, select...) will only be called when an action (collect) is called so I think every thing happens when you call your collect

Comment: Spark operations are lazily evaluated and thus all processing will happen only after action is called. If you see OOM error sometimes then I recommend to check heap util and GC patterns on driver. I can't comment much here as I am not sure what type of processing you are doing but check if data processing is consistent or it varies by some amount in cases causing OOM ( I mean filtering, transformations, joins, broadcast etc)

Comment: Another config I am suspecting is, spark.driver.maxResultSize which is set to 3g. Check size of dataset which sizeEstimator after all transformations and see if its exceeding more than 3g ?

Comment: Thanks Nachiket. Let me clarify that the script has a collect() action for each of the metrics being calculated. The data size exceeding the maxResultSize  is a possibility, however, the occasional successful runs indicate otherwise.